# The form validation returning False in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

**views.py**

```
def student_login(request):
    form = StudentLoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentLoginForm(data=request.POST)
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            print(username)
            user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('index')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'Invalid username or password!')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid username or password!')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'student_login.html',context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True,default=None)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=None,unique=True)
    total_books_due = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**forms.py**

```
class StudentLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['username','password']
        widgets = {
            'password':forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
```

**student_login.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 
<!-- {% load crispy_forms_tags %}  -->

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <br>
    
    <h2>Student Login Form</h2>
    <br>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if messages %}
            {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            
        {% endif %} <br>

        {% for field in form %} 
           <p>{{ field.label }} </p>
           <p>{{ field }} </p> 
           <br>
        {% endfor %} 
        
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
    </form>
    
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have been trying to change again and again but `form.is_valid()` is still returning `False`. I could not figure out the reason that the form is not valid because I have already specify the fields that I want to show and added the `csrf_token`. Could anyone help me to figure out where is the problem?

Comment: It shows ```<ul class="errorlist"><li>username<ul class="errorlist"><li>Student with this Username already exists.</li></ul></li><li>password<ul class="errorlist"><li>Student with this Password already exists.</li></ul></li></ul>``` but I would like to retrieve the existing username and password in order to log in the existing user

Comment: try logging form.errors

Answer (score 1):

Try to use just a simple form and not a `ModelForm`, as `ModelForm`s in the background work with creating and updating objects.

In this case, `ModelForm` is validating as if you are trying to create a new `Student`, causing the `already exists` failures.

For example, you can write a simple login form like this:

```
class StudentLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': True}))
    password = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )
```

And then in your views, use it as is:

```
def student_login(request):
    form = StudentLoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = StudentLoginForm(data=request.POST)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(
                username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
                password=form.cleaned_data.get('password'),
            )

            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('index')

        messages.error(request, 'Invalid username or password!')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'student_login.html',context)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please change this line

```
form = StudentLoginForm(data=request.POST)
```

to

```
form = StudentLoginForm(request.POST)
```

and also why you are validating the fields as you already validating using `.is_valid()`
function?

Comment: I have tried changing but still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Just create a simple form with username and password. Also, the password field should not be unique if you are using plain text.

Better to use inbuilt User model provided by django. If you want to extend fields in User model, use AbstractUser and override the User model. See in documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/